# Union Streams in Java

Tags: java, collections, lightweight-stream-api

I think this question is useless, but i can`t find how i can union this code to one line

I have List of active Couriers.
I am trying to find all free couriers in this list and after that find courier with min distance

```
List<Courier> afterCheckIsFree = activeCouriers.stream().filter(Courier::isFree).collect(Collectors.toList());
final Optional<Courier> courierWithMinDistance = afterCheckIsFree.stream()
                .filter(n -> n.getId().equals(CourierFinder.minDistanceUsingCourier(Point.ZERO_POINT, afterCheckIsFree).getId())).findFirst();
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It can almost certainly be done, but your question doesn't explain what any of these methods do. Are you trying to find the first free courier with min distance?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without knowing what `CourierFinder.minDistanceUsingCourier` does internally with `afterCheckIsFree`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `minDistanceUsingCourier` method to return the distance for a *single* courier (instead of the minimum distance of a *list* of couriers) then:

```
final Optional<Courier> courierWithMinDistance = activeCouriers.stream()
  .filter(Courier::isFree)
  .min(comparing(c -> minDistanceUsingCourier(Point.ZERO_POINT, c)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply 2 criterias on your stream: firstly, checking if courier is free, secondly, sort remaining couriers by distance and take first.
It will look like:

```
list.stream().filter(Courier::isFree).sorted((c1, c2)->c1.getDistance().
                               compareTo(c2.getDistance())).
                               findFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the actual aim is to find the courier that is both free and has the minimum distance...

Your code will run the `minDistance` algorithm for *every* courier, so it is incredibly inefficient. It can be done in one go:

```
Optional<Courier> = activeCouriers.stream()
  .filter(Courier::isFree)
  .min((c1, c2) -> c1.getDistanceFrom(ZERO_POINT) - c2.getDistanceFrom(ZERO_POINT));
```

`min` can find the minimum thing in the stream based on whatever function you want, which is what is used here.